# How do you set a custom susy layout's gutters to 0?

Tags: sass, susy-sass, susy

I'm finding myself frequently having to negate gutters with `margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;`. I tried setting gutters in a custom layout to 0

```
$my_layout: (gutters: 0);
.my_class {
  @include with-layout($my_layout) {
    ...
  }
}
```

but this does not set the gutter width to 0, it just tells susy not set gutters at all.

How do you set gutters to 0 in a susy layout (instead of just setting them to null)?

Comment: This [works fine for me](http://sassmeister.com/gist/6fbbc3e2e571fff9f3a5). I can't recreate the error.

Comment: Hmmm, alright, I'll look into it further and see if I can find what's causing it;

Comment: Could it have anything to do with `@include with-layout` being called within another mixin?

Comment: It might depend on the mixin. Can you narrow it down to a failing demo?

Comment: So the issue is that `gutters: 0` doesn't remove gutters it just tells susy not to add them. So if gutters are already set from a previous breakpoint then they will remain regardless of your layout settings. http://sassmeister.com/gist/6fbbc3e2e571fff9f3a5

Comment: oops, that link just leads back to the sassmeister demo you made. I thought I was linking to my edits. I edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: So is there no way to set gutters to zero rather just `null`?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
$my-layout: (
  gutter-override: 0%,
);
```

`gutter-override` is generally for overriding gutters on-the-fly, but Susy allows it to be set globally as well. Currently Susy ignores gutter output of `0`, but seems to allow gutter output of `0%` (or `0` with any other unit).

I'd be willing to consider adding more clear `null` vs. `0` functionality, if you want to file an issue on github.